# Sending parameters from one apk to other

Tags: android, android-intent, apk

I am able to launch an apk from the button click of other apk. but i have to send parameters also.Like if i am giving values in a text and when i click the button then it should send the parameters to other apk as well it should start other apk. I know how to send parameters between activities in the same package. Please guide me how do i do it.

**Update:**
I have successfully run that apk's. I just had to put package name instead of class name.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
`i.putExtra(param, value);//Put extra values to your intents,` if you are using intents to launch another app.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use content providers to share data across different applications in Android. [Here](http://www.androidcompetencycenter.com/2009/01/basics-of-android-part-iv-android-content-providers/)

is an example as to how to use them. You need to have a URI which identifies your dataset and use the same URI in another application to retrieve data from it.

Answer (score 0):

Use Intents, as explained in [Android Developer Documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html) or many [tutorials over the internet](http://www.desctrl.com/2011/05/16/android-intent-with-parameters/).

You should use Bundles to pass parameters, as you can read there.

Answer (score 0):

You can use files in a common directory to comminucate different apps or basicly you can have serversocket in your first app that runs the other one, so the second one can connect it and transfer data to/from first app.